# XMLInputFactory setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD,"") gives Unrecognized property

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, xml-parsing, sonarqube

Environment: Java 8 / SpringBoot v1.3.3.RELEASE

This is an old Java code base. Recently sonar was introduced and my task is to fix Critical/Blocker level security vulnerabilities.

At this code sonar recommends to "Disable access to external entities in XML parsing".

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
```

As per the sonar recommendation I added following properties to the factory,

```
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

However, when I run the unit tests it gives my following error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD'
```

But it doesn't give me the any such error when I set the same properties for the DocumentBuilderFactory as follows,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docBuilderFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
docBuilderFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

I did a bit of a research and found [This](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8015487) Java bug. But it's fixed and also it's related to TransformerFactory. Couldn't find any such bug related to XmlInputFactory though.

Any workaround or fix is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have applied the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/issues/50#issuecomment-388842419) and configured the XMLInputFactory object this way:

```
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
```

[OWASP XML External Entity Prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#xmlinputfactory-a-stax-parser)